# Terminate an application from my Cocoa code

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-leopard

I have to programmatically terminate (not forcibly) an application from my Cocoa code.
Actually, here's what it looks like:

```
-(BOOL) terminateAppWithBundle:(NSString*)bundle {
    NSArray* array = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:bundle];
    if ([array count] > 0){        
        NSRunningApplication* app = (NSRunningApplication*)[array objectAtIndex:0];
        [array makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(terminate)];
        float time = 0;
        while (!app.isTerminated){
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2];
            time += 0.2;
            if (time >= 15){
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

It works very well... but only on Snow Leopard and Lion.
On Leopard (which i would like to support) the application crashes on start with this error message:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSRunningApplication
```

I guess it's because NSRunningApplication is not part of the 10.5 SDK... how can i do the same without using that class?

Comment: Using tags in question title is unnecessary. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself with AppleScript:

```
-(BOOL) terminateiTunes {
    NSAppleScript *closeiTunes = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"iTunes\" to quit"];
    [closeXcode executeAndReturnError:nil];
    return YES;
}
```